# XQuery order by ascending and descending

Tags: xml, xquery

In XQuery, How do you order by ascending and descending?

I have got the following from a tutorial:

```
for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by $x/title
return $x/title
```

would it be

```
for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by $x/title ascending
return $x/title
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ascending` (default) or `descending` at the end of the `order by..` expression.

Here's the link to the relevant part of the W3C XQuery spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-OrderSpec

Comment: so it would befor $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by ascending $x/title
return $x/title

Comment: or would it be for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book where $x/price>30 order by  $x/title return $x/title ascending

Comment: I wrote "after the expression", which I meant like this: `... order by $x/title ascending ...` (just like you wrote in your question, this is the correct syntax).

Answer (score 1):

**See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001243/xquery-help-sorted-parent-child-relationship/6006042#6006042)**. The code demonstrates ordering in descending order.

For ordering in ascending order, the `ascending` keyword can be ommitted.